# SetState of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an object in the state that has an array. I want to set the status of the `IDs` of that array to another empty array in the state. I want the `array1[1].team.id` to be pushed to the empty array, `array2` and set status to be true. My code:

```
this.state: {

    array1: [
        {id:1, team: [
            {id:1, name: 'name1a'},
            {id:2, name: 'name2a'},
            {id:3, name: 'name3a'}
        ]},

        {id:2, team: [
            {id:1, name: 'name1b'},
            {id:2, name: 'name2b'},
            {id:3, name: 'name3b'}
        ]},

        {id:3, team: [
            {id:1, name: 'name1c'},
            {id:2, name: 'name2c'},
            {id:3, name: 'name3c'}
        ]},
    ],

    array2: [

    ]

}
```

So with the function, I want array2 to be:

```
array2: [
   {id:1, status:true},
   {id:2, status:true},
   {id:2, status:true}
]
```

I tried:

```
updateArray = (id) => {     //consider id=1

    let array2 = [...this.state.array2];

    let newArray2 = [...this.state.array1[id].team.id, status:true];

    this.setState({
        array2: newArray2
    })

}
```

And it did not work. Obviously, doing something wrong. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: There's also no `...team.id`, since `.team` is an array. Why a second array btw? Can't you just add `status: true` to the first array's team objects?

Comment: Why is there two objects with `id:2` in expected `array2`? Please create distinct ids for each object in `array1` and objects in `team` array and write a clear problem statement. It's unclear which `id` you want added in array2

Comment: @adiga lets say I want to add the array[1] ids.

Comment: So, given `id=3` from `updateArray` parameter, you want to get `array1[2].team` objects to be pushed into `array2` with `status: true`? Do you remove the existing objects from `array2` before doing this?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe what the ultimate goal is. Something like "I want a boolean `status` for each team and to be able to change it as I like using something like `setTeamStatus(id, newStatus)`"

Comment: What if `array2` already has (some of) the ids?

Comment: @ChrisG, I want array2 to have individual objects with ids from `team` of selected id from array1, and set status to true.

Comment: @trincot, The array2 will always be empty and waiting for Ids from array1[n].team and set them to true.

Comment: Ok, but where in state are you storing which team the status objects in `array2` are referring to? And if all team members have the same status, why store them individually? Also: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (we're stuck at the fifth list item currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the map function on `array1[id]`:

```
updateArray = id => {
    const array2 = this.state.array1[id].team.map(item => (
        {id: item.id, status: true}
    ));
    this.setState({array2})
}
```

I don't know if you always want to replace the values in `array2` or you need multiple new arrays to be created in the `state` depending upon the `id`s passed to the above function, like `array2`, `array3` and so on?

**UPDATE:** if the `id` isn't the same as the index of the parent array (as suggested by *adiga* and *Chris*)

```
updateArray = id => {
    const arrayToConsider = this.state.array1.find(element => (
        element.id === id
    ));
    const array2 = arrayToConsider.team.map(item => (
        {id: item.id, status: true}
    ));
    this.setState({array2})
}
```

Comment: But how do I push it to array 2? where do I put this in the function?

Comment: This seems to be the solution OP is looking for, as far as I can tell.

Comment: `array1[id]` assumes that `id`s are same as indices (which they aren't). OP probably wants `const { team = [] } = this.state.array1.find(a => a.id === id) || {}; const array2 = team.map(...)`

Comment: If the key order remains the same, maybe the `map()` method can be called on `array1[id - 1]`, so that that the index resembles the key. However, it will be a problem when one of the elements is removed.

Comment: Or use `find()` to grab the proper team array.

Comment: @adiga I have updated my answer, please feel free to edit or correct.